# Numbered Paragraphs with Multiple Levels in Reportlab

Tags: reportlab, paragraph

I'd like to create a numbered list with multiple levels in ReportLab. I've looked almost everywhere and I can only find the  tag to build a numbered list. However, when I write the following code, my list looks like this:

```
   contents.add(Paragraph("<seq/>. Level 1 Header", h1))
   contents.add(Paragraph("<seq/>. Level 2 Header", h2))    
   contents.add(Paragraph("<seq/>. Level 1 Header", h1))
```

> 1. Level 1 Header
>
>    1. Level 2 Header (< that 1 is actually 2...stackoverflow is not showing what I am writing)
> 2. Level 1 Header (< that 2 is actually 3)

Instead of something like this:

> 1. Level 1 Header
>
>    1.1 Level 2 Header
> 2. Level 2 Header

Does anyone know how to achieve that? Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT:
With @Snoozer's comment, it's now:

```
1. Level 1 Header
  2.1 Level 2 Header
3. Level 1 Header
```

...which is still incorrect. I can't find anything that holds the  value to maintain the first level index.

Comment: I think this question might have the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874329/reportlab-does-not-reset-sequences-when-creating-multiple-documents-with-table-o

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I now believe what you are trying to do isn't possible, but I have a couple of recommendations

If you don't care about the precise `#.#` formatting, you can accomplish this by using multiple `seq` tags. To easily use multiple `seq` tags, start with `seqOrder`. This has the nice property that whenever you use a higher level's seq tag, the lower levels reset. To make your levels look distinct, I suggest formatting each one differently.

```
contents.add(Paragraph( ('<seqChain order="lev1 lev2"/>'
                         '<seqFormat id="lev1" value="1">'
                         '<seqFormat id="lev2" value="a">'
                         '<seq id="levelOne"/>. Level 1 Header'), h1))
contents.add(Paragraph('<seq id="levelTwo"/> Level 2 Header', h2))    
contents.add(Paragraph('<seq id="levelOne"/>. Level 1 Header', h1))
#We didn't have to reset the level 2 tag because chain takes care of it
contents.add(Paragraph('<seq id="levelTwo"/> Level 2 Header', h2))
```

I found page 47 of [ReportLab's RML userguide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml2pdf-userguide.pdf) helpful here. I attempted to store the value of the current upper level using a `<name\>` tag, but after 1 use it does not appear that a `<name\>` tag can be reassigned. I thought about other programmatic ways to keep track of this in python, but at this point you're pretty much writing the list yourself. One example would be

```
level1 = 1
contents.add(Paragraph('{0}. Level 1 Header'.format(level1), h1))
level2 = 1 
contents.add(Paragraph('{0}.{1} Level 2 Header'.format(level1,level2), h2))
#Now we have to automatically increment level1
level1 += 1    
contents.add(Paragraph('{0}. Level 1 Header'.format(level1), h1))
#and manually reset level 2
level2 = 1
contents.add(Paragraph('{0}.{1} Level 2 Header'.format(level1,level2), h2))
```

Although you could define a function that would append a paragraph for you and manually iterate/reset the appropriate level values.

I'm not sure you're doing this in python - I know RML is part of the commercial version of reportlab, and I've never built a document by adding RML tags. If you are using python however, you might want to look at building your document with `Flowables`, and there is a `ListFlowable` to create these sorts of lists. You will still not be able to create a list with the label in the format you desire, as the `ListFlowable` is merely an interface to these RML tags. You can learn more about `Flowables` in the [ReportLab User Guide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) on page 86

Comment: The header indices are still incorrect even with id. I couldn't get the format to look right here, so please see modification above.