# Reportlab does not reset sequences when creating multiple documents with table of contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

I am using a template function that creates multiple PDF documents in one program execution using reportlab.

These documents are identical by structure and have identical headings. They only differ in content below the headings. All of these documents contain a table of contents element.

I am using sequence tags (`<seq/>` etc.) to create numbered headings e. g.

```
1. Top1
  1.1 Sub1
2. Top2
  2.1 Sub1
  2.2 Sub2
```

This works well for one single document but as soon as I create a second one right after the first the sequences are not reset and the second document's TOC looks like

```
2. Top1
  2.1 Sub1
3. Top2
  3.1 Sub1
  3.2 Sub2
```

Creating a third document `Top1` will start with `3`.

But since I am starting a new document, creating a new `BaseDocTemplate` class, I was expecting the sequences to be reset. How can I achieve that?

I've tried to create a small as possible example using one of the tutorials for reportlab.

```
from  reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle as PS
from  reportlab.platypus import PageBreak
from  reportlab.platypus.paragraph import Paragraph
from  reportlab.platypus.doctemplate import PageTemplate, BaseDocTemplate
from  reportlab.platypus.tableofcontents import TableOfContents
from  reportlab.platypus.frames import Frame
from  reportlab.lib.units import cm

class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):
     def __init__(self, filename, **kw):
         self.allowSplitting = 0
         super().__init__(filename, **kw)
         template = PageTemplate('normal', [Frame(2.5*cm, 2.5*cm, 15*cm, 25*cm, id='F1')])
         self.addPageTemplates(template)

# Entries to the table of contents can be done either manually by
# calling the addEntry method on the TableOfContents object or automatically
# by sending a 'TOCEntry' notification in the afterFlowable method of
# the DocTemplate you are using. The data to be passed to notify is a list
# of three or four items countaining a level number, the entry text, the page
# number and an optional destination key which the entry should point to.
# This list will usually be created in a document template's method like
# afterFlowable(), making notification calls using the notify() method
# with appropriate data.

     def afterFlowable(self, flowable):
         "Registers TOC entries."
         if flowable.__class__.__name__ == 'Paragraph':
             text = flowable.getPlainText()
             style = flowable.style.name
             if style == 'Heading1':
                 self.notify('TOCEntry', (0, text, self.page))
             if style == 'Heading2':
                 self.notify('TOCEntry', (1, text, self.page))


centered = PS(name = 'centered',
    fontSize = 30,
    leading = 16,
    alignment = 1,
    spaceAfter = 20)

h1 = PS(
    name = 'Heading1',
    fontSize = 14,
    leading = 16)


h2 = PS(name = 'Heading2',
    fontSize = 12,
    leading = 14)

# Heading definition with sequence numbers
heading = {
    1 : "<seq id='h1'/>.<seqreset id='h2'/><seqreset id='h3'/> {}",
    2 : "<seq id='h1' inc='no'/>.<seq id='h2'/><seqreset id='h3'/> {}",
    3 : "<seq id='h1' inc='no'/>.<seq id='h2' inc='no'/>.<seq id='h3'/> {}",
}

def build_document(filename):
    # Build story.
    story = []

    # Create an instance of TableOfContents. Override the level styles (optional)
    # and add the object to the story

    toc = TableOfContents()
    toc.levelStyles = [
        PS(fontName='Times-Bold', fontSize=20, name='TOCHeading1', leftIndent=20, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=10, leading=16),
        PS(fontSize=18, name='TOCHeading2', leftIndent=40, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=5, leading=12),
    ]
    story.append(toc)

    story.append(Paragraph('<b>Table of contents</b>', centered))
    story.append(PageBreak())
    story.append(Paragraph(heading[1].format('First heading'), h1))
    story.append(Paragraph('Text in first heading', PS('body')))
    story.append(Paragraph(heading[2].format('First sub heading'), h2))
    story.append(Paragraph('Text in first sub heading', PS('body')))
    story.append(PageBreak())
    story.append(Paragraph(heading[2].format('Second sub heading'), h2))
    story.append(Paragraph('Text in second sub heading', PS('body')))
    story.append(PageBreak())
    story.append(Paragraph(heading[2].format('Last heading'), h1))
    doc = MyDocTemplate(filename)
    doc.multiBuild(story)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    build_document("1.pdf")
    build_document("2.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a quick solution which solves my problem but which I don't like as a final solution.

The problem is that I am using global sequences with the same name. `h1`, `h2` and `h3` appear in every document. And reportlab doesn't seem to reset them when a new document is started. So instead I reset the manually before filling the story list.

```
def build_document(filename):
    # Build story. story = []

    # Reset the sequences
    story.append(Paragraph("<seqreset id='h1'/>", PS('body')))
    story.append(Paragraph("<seqreset id='h2'/>", PS('body')))
    story.append(Paragraph("<seqreset id='h3'/>", PS('body')))

    # ...  rest of the code from the question
```

Comment: Isn't just the first `<seqreset id='h1'/>` sufficient? The others are already reset when using `h1` for the first time?

Comment: @B8vrede no. It doesn't seem to be sufficient. I have tested it and the sequence is still incremented. I know that it is possible to chain sequences and then reseting `h1` would be enough but in my example they seem not to be chained.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `reportlab.lib.sequencer.Sequencer` object being used is global.

You can reset all counters by supplying a new Sequencer

```
    from reportlab.lib.sequencer import setSequencer, Sequencer

    
    setSequencer(Sequencer())
```

You can reset a single counter by doing something like:

```
    from reportlab.lib.sequencer import getSequencer

    s = getSequencer()
    s.reset('h1')
```

You could also try using Sequencer directly instead of injecting XML.

> Class Sequencer: Something to make it easy to number paragraphs,
> sections, images and anything else. The features include registering
> new string formats for sequences, and 'chains' whereby some counters
> are reset when their parents. It keeps track of a number of
> 'counters', which are created on request.

```
Usage::
 >>> seq = Sequencer()
 >>> seq.next('Bullets')
 1
 >>> seq.next('Bullets')
 2
 >>> seq.next('Bullets')
 3
 >>> seq.reset('Bullets')
 >>> seq.next('Bullets')
 1
 >>> seq.next('Figures')
 1
 >>>
```